# If PostgreSQL count(*) is always slow how to paginate complex queries?

Tags: performance, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

If PostgreSQL's `count(*)` is [always slow](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting) how to paginate complex queries?

Making triggers doesn't seem to be a good solution as long as in this case we have a lot of pages (for example different categories, filters, etc).

What to do if `VACUUM/VACUUM ANALYZE/ANALYZE/VACUUM FULL` doesn't help? What are the best practices to use `count(*)` with postgresql?

Comment: Count, (and any other aggregate function) on any criteria is wholly dependent on useful indexes, no matter what DBMS.

Comment: How does a `count(*)` relate to paging? Can you show us the statement you are using? Do you run an extra `count(*)` before running the actual query? Did you try to do the `count(*)` together with the main query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `count(*)` is used to count amount of pages. My statement is simple `SELECT count(*) from my_table` (which runs very slow) and `select count(pub_date) from catalog_ad where "catalog_ad"."pub_date" >= '2013-04-20 00:00:00';` (which is faster, but still slow). I run `count` separately of main query. How do I run them together?

Comment: See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/92045/1  You also might want to read this: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results for some deeper information on how to speed up paging.

Comment: Check [my recent answer on how to do pagination with conditions and a single count](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16842749/131874).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you read the heading on that article?

> Note that the following article only applies to versions of PostgreSQL prior to 9.2. Index-only scans are now implemented.

Use 9.2 and you'll generally find you get much better results. Read [the index-only scans wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) for details.

That said, on older versions using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` generally works fine. You can estimate rowcounts (and therefore pagecounts) using the table statistics if you don't mind a bit of variation. See "Estimating row count" [in the article you already linked to](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting).

Paginating using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` is, IMO, an anti-pattern anyway. A lot of the time you can rephrase your pagination code so it uses `sort_column > 'last_seen_value' LIMIT 100`, i.e. it avoids the offset. This can sometimes result in very large performance gains.

Comment: @Daniil You already linked to the answer; just read http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Counting, "Estimating row count"

Comment: that's pretty good solution when I want to count rows in the whole table, but what if I want to filter table?

Comment: @Daniil Count will generally be able to use an index for a query with a filter. It still has to do heap lookups until 9.2, but unless you're doing a filter that matches most of the table should perform OK. Otherwise: Upgrade.

Comment: @Daniil Remember to read the manual on upgrading; remember it isn't an in-place upgrade, you need to use `pg_upgrade` or dump and reload.

Comment: just upgraded to 9.2. Nothing changed

Comment: @Daniil `explain (buffers, analyze)` then, please; let's see what it's doing.

Comment: I have the same problem. I.e. I need to paginate over filtered results. Filter is variety of user-defined settings, i.e. it has "over 9000" variations. So caching the count is not a (viable) option. I've put the queries and their explains here: https://gist.github.com/NoICE/59a915e4b2b522e574e8 Any hint/help would be much appreciated! :-) P.S. I don't know why adding the joins (as seen in the gist) produces such terrible performance dropdown (as it is indexed, it should NOT imo...).

Comment: While Query PLAN estimate works, I could run that under JPA. JPA do not allow me to get the result from trigger function.

Comment: According to [_Is "count(*)" much faster now?_](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans#Is_.22count.28.2A.29.22_much_faster_now.3F) this might be the reason: _"Index-only scans *can* be used to satisfy these queries [...]. However, in practice that isn't particularly likely. [...] "count(*) without any predicate" queries will only use an index-only scan if the index is significantly smaller than its table. This typically only happens when the table's row width is much wider than some indexes'. "_

Comment: @CraigRinger Here is the `explain (buffers, analyze)` you requested for my example data: https://gist.github.com/nh2/bbbff93be04ea6c5181ec948981081b1 -- Do you know why the equivalent of `Index Only Scan using categories_pkey on categories` from the [index-only scans wiki page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) you linked isn't kicking in here? Can we force it to kick in?

Comment: In my case, `VACUUM ANALYZE mytable;` helped: After it I see `Index Only Scan` in the `explain` (see my [gist](https://gist.github.com/nh2/bbbff93be04ea6c5181ec948981081b1#edit-vacuum-analyze-seems-to-help)) and I got a 2x speedup.

Comment: ... and a 20x speedup with [cold buffer cache](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87908/how-do-you-empty-the-buffers-and-cache-on-a-linux-system). Also want to leave here that just `ANALYZE` didn't do the job, `VACUUM ANALYZE` did.

Answer (score 16):

If you're doing SELECT count(*) FROM table and have pg stats enabled you can use the lower example, which in this case goes from 13ms down to 0.05ms.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM news;
```

26171

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT count(*) FROM news;
```

Total runtime: 13.057 ms

```
SELECT reltuples::bigint AS count FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'public.news'::regclass;
```

26171

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT reltuples::bigint AS count FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'public.news'::regclass;
```

Total runtime: 0.053 ms

Comment: To confirm the performance difference: `(0.4ms)  SELECT reltuples::bigint AS count FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'public.aggregate_data_points'::regclass` vs. `(398.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "aggregate_data_points"`

Comment: These two queries give different results.

Comment: Take into account the second query (with reltuples) is an estimate only, it will not always yield the exact value.

Comment: @JhulianoMorenoHow close is the estimate? And what effects this estimate

Comment: How can you add filters like where clauses to this?